# ThingsBoard Widget Dimension Disturbed the content

Tags: thingsboard

I face an issue with the ThingsBoard. When I open the dashboard on another computer with a different screen resolution. The content in the widget is disturbed. Does anyone tell me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the ThingsBoard Widgets are responsive to different Screen Resolutions and even Mobile Views.
Which Widgets are you using?

Also it is helpful during development of ThingsBoard Widgets to test the behaviour for different screens. You can use the developer tools in your browser for this:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/